# I get a TypeError: Cannot read property '402' of undefined, where does it come from?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, node-red

First forgive my English, not my 1st language, sorry !
I'm setting up a data-collector for some Siemens PLC with Node-red. I'm trying to put in place an archive for the errors of the PLC but looks like I'm having troubles with my arrays.
I have 404 PLC Errors I'm trying to collect, I need to know when one of them appears and disappears. I could have multiple errors at the same time too, so I need to keep track of which is there and which is not.

I don't have any debug extensive debug on what's happening but it looks like some of my arrays, I suspect the Date ones don't work or even exist.

```
//tabDef is an array with 404 strings in it, I don't show it there
var payload = msg.payload;
var topic = msg.topic
var tabEtat = context.get("Etat");
var tabStart = context.get("Start");
var tabEnd = context.get('End');
var Query;
var time;
var timeDef;
var StimeDef;
var date;

function GetTime (date){
    h = date.getHours();
    m = date.getMinutes();
    s = date.getSeconds();
    var t = [h,m,s];
    return t;
}

for(i = 0 ; i < tabDef.length ; i++){
    if((tabDef[i]==topic) && (payload === true) && (payload !== tabEtat[i])){
        tabEtat = context.get("Etat");
        tabEtat[i] = true;
        context.set("Etat", tabEtat);
        time = new Date();
        time = time.getTime()+time.getTimezoneOffset(60);
        tabStart = context.get("Start");
        tabStart[i] = time;
        context.set("Start", tabStart);
    }else if((tabDef[i]==topic) && (payload === false) && (payload !== tabEtat[i])){
        tabEtat = context.get("Etat");
        tabEtat[i] = false;
        context.set("Etat", tabEtat);
        time = new Date();
        time = time.getTime()+time.getTimezoneOffset(60);
        tabEnd = context.get("End");
        tabEnd[i] = time;
        context.set("End", tabEnd);
        var Start = context.get('Start');
        Start = Start[i];
        var StartDiff = GetTime(Start);
        var EndDiff = GetTime(time);
        for(j = 0; j < StartDiff.length; j++){
            timeDef[j] = EndDiff[i] - StartDiff[i];
        }
        StimeDef = (""+timeDef[0]+""+timeDef[1]+""+timeDef[2]+"");

        Query = "INSERT INTO Defauts(Heure, Nom, Duree) VALUES ('"+Start+"','"+topic+"','"+StimeDef+"');";
        msg.payload = Query;

        return msg;
    }
}
```

What I would like to see is the formated query returning something like
"some ISODate" + "The PLC Error" + "How much time between apparition and disparition".

Comment: What is `tabDef`? What's the difference between `context.get("Etat")` and `context.get("Etat", tabEtat)`? You reassign `tabDef` in your loop, propably at some point it's assigned to undefined. Note that you also reuse `i` in your inner `for` loop - is it expected?

Comment: **tabDef** is an array containing 404 strings, as for the **context.get** are the same, just a mistake from my part... I don't see the reassignement. As for the **i** in the loop, I'm not sure it's having a big impact but I can change it for another letter.

Comment: You're getting this error on `tabEtat[i]` or `Start[i]` when `i` is 402, but it's hard to say why, as there are many unknown variables. Since `tabDef` has 404 elements and you get this error on index 402 maybe it would be enough to show last 5 elements, example for `topic` and `payload`

Comment: Won't work, I can have any error coming from the PLC, I need to check all the array. I use the index as memory for the state(Etat) and date of the error. I was thinking it was coming from the date because I have some troubles with them by the past... And 402 is just a string in `tabDef`. `topic` contains a string wich is exactly the same as in `tabDef` and payload is a boolean

Comment: Looking at this error and your code, 402 can't be a string in `tabDef`, it's index of `tabDef`. BTW shouldn't `timeDef = EndDiff[i] - EndDiff[i];` be `timeDef[j] = EndDiff[j] - StartDiff[j];`? I also see that you set "Start"'s value only in first case and reuse `Start` variable in second case, so my guess is that at index 401 your `Start = Start[i]` sets reference of `Start` to undefined and at index 402 `context.get("Start")` returns undefined

Comment: Okay I see. I want to have what's in my array at any index so could 402 as it could be 50. You're right for `timeDef`. Start is when the error is catch, I think I can reuse it as I reassign the value of my array of date with the `context.get("Start)`

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's 402 or 50, "Cannot read property 'someproperty' of undefined" means that you have in your code construction like `somevariable['someproperty']` or `var name = 'someproperty'; somevariable[name]` where value of `somevariable` is **undefined**. If you get this error on `Start[i]` it means that `Start` is undefined and you attempted to read property of name equal to value of `i`.